# JavaFX Simplest Way to Set Tableview Cell Background Color using Index

Tags: javafx, tableview

[Click here to view my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6lWC.png) Is there any simplest way to set tableview cell background color in javafx using table index values without using cellfactory function.Iam looking simple single line of code like this

```
int rowIndex=0;
int colIndex=1;
setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;",(rowIndex,colIndex));
```

i know the simple code to get cell data using table index is

```
   String a=personTable.getColumns().get(0).getCellObservableValue(1).‌​getValue().toString(‌​);
   System.out.println("value"+a)
```

Controller.java

```
    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{
     @FXML //  fx:id="fruitCombo"
     private ComboBox<String> yearCombo;   
    @FXML
private TableView<SoccerTeam> personTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> monthname;
@FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d1;
    @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d2;
     @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d3;
      @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d4;
       @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d5;
        @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d6;
         @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d7;
          @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d8;
           @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d9;
            @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d10;

        @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d11;
    @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d12;
     @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d13;
      @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d14;
       @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d15;
        @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d16;
         @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d17;
          @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d18;
           @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d19;
            @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d20;

    @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d21;
    @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d22;
     @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d23;
      @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d24;
       @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d25;
        @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d26;
         @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d27;
          @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d28;
           @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d29;
            @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d30;
    @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d31;
    @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d32;
     @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d33;
      @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d34;
       @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d35;
        @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d36;
         @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d37;
          @FXML
private TableColumn<SoccerTeam, String> d[];


      final ObservableList<SoccerTeam> teams = FXCollections.observableArrayList();





@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    //final TableView<SoccerTeam> teamTable = new TableView<>();
        monthname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("monthname"));




    d1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d1"));

    d2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d2"));

    d3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d3"));

    d4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d4"));

    d5.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d5"));

    d6.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d6"));

    d7.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d7"));  
    d8.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d8"));

    d9.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d9"));

    d10.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d10"));
    d11.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d11"));

    d12.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d12"));

    d13.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d13"));

    d14.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d14"));

    d15.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d15"));

    d16.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d16"));

    d17.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d17"));  
    d18.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d18"));

    d19.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d19"));

    d20.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d20"));
       d21.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d21"));

    d22.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d22"));

    d23.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d23"));

    d24.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d24"));

    d25.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d25"));

    d26.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d26"));

    d27.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d27"));  
    d28.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d28"));

    d29.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d29"));

    d30.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d30"));
       d31.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d31"));

    d32.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d32"));

    d33.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d33"));

    d34.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d34"));

    d35.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d35"));

    d36.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d36"));

    d37.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<SoccerTeam, String>("d37")); 



     yearCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
  @Override 
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> selected, String year,String newyear) {

             teams.clear();

              addjanuvary(newyear);

              addfebruvary(newyear);








       }               
       });
       personTable.setItems(teams); 
       ;




      }


 void addjanuvary(String newyear) {

               Calendar day= new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(newyear), Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
                int dayOfWeek = day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
                  System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
               switch(dayOfWeek)

              {

               case 1:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("JANUVARY", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
                   break;
                  case 2:
                 teams.add(new SoccerTeam("JANUVARY", "", "1", "2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31", "", "", "", "", ""));
                 break;
                  case 3:

                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("JANUVARY", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31","","","",""));
                  break;
                  case 4:
                  teams.add(new SoccerTeam("JANUVARY", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31", "", "", ""));
                  break;
                  case 5:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("JANUVARY", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31", "",""));
                    break;

                  case 6:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("JANUVARY", "", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31",""));
                 break;
                  case 7:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("JANUVARY", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30","31"));
                 break;
                  default:

                  System.out.println("no");
                break;
              }
 }







    private void addfebruvary(String newyear) {


               GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();    

          if(cal.isLeapYear(Integer.parseInt(newyear)))
          {
             System.out.println("case1");
              System.out.print("Given year is leap year.");

              Calendar day= new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(newyear), Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1);
                int dayOfWeek = day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
                  System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
              switch(dayOfWeek)

              {

               case 1:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "","", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
                   break;
                  case 2:
                 teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "1", "2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "", "", "", "","", "", ""));
                 break;
                  case 3:

                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "", "", "", "", "",""));
                  break;
                  case 4:
                  teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "","", "", "", ""));
                  break;
                  case 5:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "","",  "", ""));
                    break;

                  case 6:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "", "", ""));
                 break;
                  case 7:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "", ""));
                 break;
                  default:

                  System.out.println("no");
                break;
              }

          }
        else
              {
                     System.out.print("Given year is not leap year.");
            Calendar day= new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(newyear), Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1);
                int dayOfWeek = day.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 
                  System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
              switch(dayOfWeek)

              {

               case 1:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "", "","", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
                   break;
                  case 2:
                 teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "1", "2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "", "", "", "", "","", "", ""));
                 break;
                  case 3:

                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "", "", "", "", "", "",""));
                  break;
                  case 4:
                  teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "", "","", "", "", ""));
                  break;
                  case 5:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "", "","",  "", ""));
                    break;

                  case 6:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "", "", "", ""));
                 break;
                  case 7:
                      teams.add(new SoccerTeam("FEBRUVARY", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1","2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9","10","11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20","21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "", "", ""));
                 break;
                  default:

                  System.out.println("no");
                break;

              }         



                      }
          }


  }
```

SoccerTeam.java

```
    public class SoccerTeam
   {

    private final SimpleStringProperty monthname;
    private final SimpleStringProperty d1;
      private final SimpleStringProperty d2;
       private final SimpleStringProperty d3;
        private final SimpleStringProperty d4;
         private final SimpleStringProperty d5;
          private final SimpleStringProperty d6;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d7;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d8;
          private final SimpleStringProperty d9;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d10;
            private final SimpleStringProperty d11;
      private final SimpleStringProperty d12;
       private final SimpleStringProperty d13;
        private final SimpleStringProperty d14;
         private final SimpleStringProperty d15;
          private final SimpleStringProperty d16;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d17;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d18;
          private final SimpleStringProperty d19;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d20;
            private final SimpleStringProperty d21;
      private final SimpleStringProperty d22;
       private final SimpleStringProperty d23;
        private final SimpleStringProperty d24;
         private final SimpleStringProperty d25;
          private final SimpleStringProperty d26;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d27;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d28;
          private final SimpleStringProperty d29;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d30;
            private final SimpleStringProperty d31;
      private final SimpleStringProperty d32;
       private final SimpleStringProperty d33;
        private final SimpleStringProperty d34;
         private final SimpleStringProperty d35;
          private final SimpleStringProperty d36;
           private final SimpleStringProperty d37;



    SoccerTeam(String monthname, String d1,String d2,String d3,String d4,String d5,String d6,String d7,String d8,String d9,String d10,
            String d11,String d12,String d13,String d14,String d15,String d16,String d17,String d18,String d19,String d20,
            String d21,String d22,String d23,String d24,String d25,String d26,String d27,String d28,String d29,String d30,
            String d31,String d32,String d33,String d34,String d35,String d36,String d37) {
        this.monthname = new SimpleStringProperty(monthname);
        this.d1 = new SimpleStringProperty(d1);
         this.d2 = new SimpleStringProperty(d2);    
          this.d3 = new SimpleStringProperty(d3);
           this.d4 = new SimpleStringProperty(d4);
            this.d5 = new SimpleStringProperty(d5);
             this.d6 = new SimpleStringProperty(d6);
              this.d7 = new SimpleStringProperty(d7);
               this.d8 = new SimpleStringProperty(d8);
             this.d9 = new SimpleStringProperty(d9);
              this.d10 = new SimpleStringProperty(d10);
                this.d11 = new SimpleStringProperty(d11);
         this.d12 = new SimpleStringProperty(d12);    
          this.d13 = new SimpleStringProperty(d13);
           this.d14 = new SimpleStringProperty(d14);
            this.d15 = new SimpleStringProperty(d15);
             this.d16 = new SimpleStringProperty(d16);
              this.d17 = new SimpleStringProperty(d17);
               this.d18 = new SimpleStringProperty(d18);
             this.d19 = new SimpleStringProperty(d19);
              this.d20 = new SimpleStringProperty(d20);
                this.d21 = new SimpleStringProperty(d21);
         this.d22 = new SimpleStringProperty(d22);    
          this.d23 = new SimpleStringProperty(d23);
           this.d24 = new SimpleStringProperty(d24);
            this.d25 = new SimpleStringProperty(d25);
             this.d26 = new SimpleStringProperty(d26);
              this.d27 = new SimpleStringProperty(d27);
               this.d28 = new SimpleStringProperty(d28);
             this.d29 = new SimpleStringProperty(d29);
              this.d30 = new SimpleStringProperty(d30);
                this.d31 = new SimpleStringProperty(d31);
         this.d32 = new SimpleStringProperty(d32);    
          this.d33 = new SimpleStringProperty(d33);
           this.d34 = new SimpleStringProperty(d34);
            this.d35 = new SimpleStringProperty(d35);
             this.d36 = new SimpleStringProperty(d36);
              this.d37 = new SimpleStringProperty(d37);


    }


    public String getMonthname() {
        return monthname.get();
    }

      public void setMonthname(String Monthname) {
       monthname.set(Monthname);
    }

    public String getD1() {
        return d1.get();
    }

   public void setD1(String D1) {
        d1.set(D1);
    }
    public String getD2() {
        return d2.get();
    }

   public void setD2(String D2) {
        d2.set(D2);
    }

    public String getD3() {
        return d3.get();
    }

   public void setD3(String D3) {
        d3.set(D3);
    } 
    public String getD4() {
        return d4.get();
    }

   public void setD4(String D4) {
        d4.set(D4);
    }

          public String getD5() {
        return d5.get();
    }

   public void setD5(String D5) {
        d5.set(D5);
    }

    public String getD6() {
        return d6.get();
    }

   public void setD6(String D6) {
        d6.set(D6);
    } 
    public String getD7() {
        return d7.get();
    }

   public void setD7(String D7) {
        d7.set(D7);
    }
          public String getD8() {
        return d8.get();
    }

   public void setD8(String D8) {
        d8.set(D8);
    }

    public String getD9() {
        return d9.get();
    }

   public void setD9(String D9) {
        d9.set(D9);
    } 
    public String getD10() {
        return d10.get();
    }

   public void setD10(String D10) {
        d10.set(D10);
    }
     public String getD11() {
        return d11.get();
    }

   public void setD11(String D11) {
        d11.set(D11);
    }
    public String getD12() {
        return d12.get();
    }

   public void setD12(String D12) {
        d12.set(D12);
    }

    public String getD13() {
        return d13.get();
    }

   public void setD13(String D13) {
        d13.set(D13);
    } 
    public String getD14() {
        return d14.get();
    }

   public void setD14(String D14) {
        d14.set(D14);
    }

          public String getD15() {
        return d15.get();
    }

   public void setD15(String D15) {
        d15.set(D15);
    }

    public String getD16() {
        return d16.get();
    }

   public void setD16(String D16) {
        d16.set(D16);
    } 
    public String getD17() {
        return d17.get();
    }

   public void setD17(String D17) {
        d17.set(D17);
    }
          public String getD18() {
        return d18.get();
    }

   public void setD18(String D18) {
        d18.set(D18);
    }

    public String getD19() {
        return d19.get();
    }

   public void setD19(String D19) {
        d19.set(D19);
    } 
    public String getD20() {
        return d20.get();
    }

   public void setD20(String D20) {
        d20.set(D20);
    }
     public String getD21() {
        return d21.get();
    }

   public void setD21(String D21) {
        d21.set(D21);
    }
    public String getD22() {
        return d22.get();
    }

   public void setD22(String D22) {
        d22.set(D22);
    }

    public String getD23() {
        return d23.get();
    }

   public void setD23(String D23) {
        d23.set(D23);
    } 
    public String getD24() {
        return d24.get();
    }

   public void setD24(String D24) {
        d24.set(D24);
    }

          public String getD25() {
        return d25.get();
    }

   public void setD25(String D25) {
        d25.set(D25);
    }

    public String getD26() {
        return d26.get();
    }

   public void setD26(String D26) {
        d26.set(D26);
    } 
    public String getD27() {
        return d27.get();
    }

   public void setD27(String D27) {
        d27.set(D27);
    }
          public String getD28() {
        return d28.get();
    }

   public void setD28(String D28) {
        d28.set(D28);
    }

    public String getD29() {
        return d29.get();
    }

   public void setD29(String D29) {
        d29.set(D29);
    } 
    public String getD30() {
        return d30.get();
    }

   public void setD30(String D30) {
        d30.set(D30);
    }
     public String getD31() {
        return d31.get();
    }

   public void setD31(String D31) {
        d31.set(D31);
    }
    public String getD32() {
        return d32.get();
    }

   public void setD32(String D32) {
        d32.set(D32);
    }

    public String getD33() {
        return d33.get();
    }

   public void setD33(String D33) {
        d33.set(D33);
    } 
    public String getD34() {
        return d34.get();
    }

   public void setD34(String D34) {
        d34.set(D34);
    }

          public String getD35() {
        return d35.get();
    }

   public void setD35(String D35) {
        d35.set(D35);
    }

    public String getD36() {
        return d36.get();
    }

   public void setD36(String D36) {
        d36.set(D36);
    } 
    public String getD37() {
        return d37.get();
    }

   public void setD37(String D37) {
        d37.set(D37);
    }



}
```

Comment: "Without `cellFactory` function" - no. The cell factory is the only way you can do this.

Comment: Also, the code you are using to get the value in the cell is highly inefficient, and too convoluted. To get the data in the table, you should just refer to the data model, not to the UI. You can do `personTable.getItems().get(1)` to get the value represented by the entire row, and then just get the property that is displayed by the first column.

Comment: Why iam using index method means i have 40 columns in my table and no  idea how to set background color(not for all cells,only to indicate absent or present of an employee)using cellfactory method.

Comment: It sounds like you are approaching this in completely the wrong way. It really doesn't matter how many columns you have. You need to explain what you are actually trying to do, and post some code showing how you are trying to do this.

Comment: iam making anual attendence report of employees using  tableview so according to employee present or absence on particular day the background color of corresponding cell(day)will change.

Comment: So that data will be in the model for the row, so just access it from the model in your cell factory. It's impossible to answer the question unless you post the code showing how you have set up the table and columns.

Comment: i have added demo of my table.You can see the link at the top

Comment: As I said in the previous comment: "It's impossible to answer the question unless you post the code showing how you have set up the table and columns."

Comment: As you said i have updated my question with codes.You can go through that

Comment: Guys try to scroll that code fast and you will see how that annotations turns into Niagara falls :D

Comment: It is a custom calendar which is not available in javafx controls.And forgive to this beginner for my bad coding

Comment: Yeah that's utterly awful. Java supports things called "arrays", "lists" and "loops". You should use them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really bad, try to do something with that. About your question:

```
// Custom rendering of the table cell.
YOUR_COLUMN.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<SoccerTeam, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(SoccerTeam item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            //Write your condition there,that is an example
            if (item == null) {
                setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

[Source](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.But i have 40 coloumns.So should i write code for all the columns?

Comment: In my case i dont want a cell with fixed background.iam making anual attendence report of employees using tableview so according to employee present or absence on particular day the background color of corresponding cell(day)will change.

Comment: @AmeenAmi "i have 40 columns" -> You should run the code in a [loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), setting a cell factory for each column.  I recommend taking some of these courses to [learn java basics](http://www.google.com/search?q=learn+java+basics) *before* attempting to create JavaFX programs.